# Finding common values in a Dataframe and inserting into a new Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Let say I have the following dataframe in Python:

```
     A B
1    1 2
2    1 3
3    1 4
4    2 3
5    2 5
6    4 2
7    5 3
8    5 4
```

How can I search both columns A & B for common values and extract both the distinct and common values into a new dataframe below:

For example:

- value 1 and 2 has a common value of 3
- value 2 and 3 has a common value of 5

[image]

```
     A B C
1    1 2 3
2    1 2 4
3    2 3 5
```

Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand the logic. How do you say 'value 1 and 2 has a common value of 3'? The picture is meaningless without anymore context.

Comment: @JarroVGIT I'll try my best to explain. Treat the values in Column A & B as a person:

User 1 knows User 2 and at the same time, knows User 3. User 2 in the other hand, knows User 3 meaning all 3 users (User 1, 2, 3) knows each other.

Comment: Ah okay that actually made it perfectly clear, thanks!

Comment: @schizetia !There is one additional connected triangle `2 - 4 - 5`: - `2 --> 5`, `5 --> 4` , `4 --> 2`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/introduction.html) lib to generate simple undirected Graph from edge list (obtained from pairs of columns `[A, B]` of the input `df`) and find connected "triangles" of nodes with [`nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G)`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.enumerate_all_cliques.html#enumerate-all-cliques):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
# assuming df is your initial dataframe
G.add_edges_from(df.to_numpy().tolist())
tri_df = pd.DataFrame([x for x in nx.enumerate_all_cliques(G) if len(x) == 3],
                      columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(tri_df)
```

---

```
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  1  2  4
2  2  3  5
3  2  4  5
```

---

Visualized graph:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...

nx.draw(G, pos=nx.circular_layout(G), node_color='green', with_labels=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright I had a go at it. It's not elegant (at all) but I tried to make it as clear as possible what the thought process was/is.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 2, 6: 4, 7: 5, 8: 5},
 'B': {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 3, 5: 5, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 4}})

# append the df again, but with A and B columns switched (now, every relationship is covered in A -> B)
df = pd.concat([df, df.rename(columns={'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'})]).reset_index(drop=True)

# Create a list of all known relationships of A, including reference to itself.
df['knowsA'] = df.apply(lambda r: df[df['A']==r['A']]['B'].to_list() + [r['A']], axis=1)
# Create a list of all known relationships of B, including reference to itself.
df['knowsB'] = df.apply(lambda r: df[df['A']==r['B']]['B'].to_list() + [r['B']], axis=1)

# Create the intersection of both lists, and sort them (for comparison later on).
df['intersection'] = df.apply(lambda r: sorted(set(r['knowsA']) & set(r['knowsB'])), axis=1)

# Filter for three way relationships, and convert them to string in order to drop duplicates.
intermediate = df[df['intersection'].apply(lambda x: len(x)==3)]['intersection'].astype(str).drop_duplicates()

# Filter the original DF and create a new dataframe with the right colums:
result = pd.DataFrame(df.filter(list(intermediate.index), axis=0)['intersection'].to_list(), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(result)
#    A  B  C
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  1  2  4
# 2  2  3  5
# 3  2  4  5
```